# Getting ssh error while deploying to server using gitlab ci

Tags: ssh, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

I set up my gitlab-runner at server A, and want to deploy to test environment at server B via ssh. I followed [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html%20gitlab-ssh-keys) from gitlab docs:

1. create ssh key pair with ssh-keygen at server A
2. add the private key as variable to the project on gitlab
3. add the public key to authorized_key file at server B
4. run ssh-agent during the deployment-job, and try to ssh to server B from server A

Here is the build details of my deployment stage:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Shell executor...
Running on phxszap09...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at b3adbe0 test ci
From http://10.0.15.60/duxiang/mediaExpress
   b3adbe0..5eb8d4d  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 5eb8d4db as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ which ssh-agent || (sudo yum update -y && sudo yum install openssh-client -y)
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 16954
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (/dev/fd/63)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh -vvv mediaexpress@10.0.15.61
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to 10.0.15.61 [10.0.15.61] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/identity type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/identity-cert type -1

debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa.

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

debug3: key_read: missing keytype

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'

debug3: key_read: missing keytype

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3

debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP

debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005

debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256

debug2: bits set: 533/1024

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY

debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149

debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 10.0.15.61 filename /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts

debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 10.0.15.61 filename /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts

debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1

debug1: Host '10.0.15.61' is known and matches the RSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug2: bits set: 528/1024

debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

debug2: kex_derive_keys

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213

debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f919c065b30)

debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/identity ((nil))

debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))

debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))

debug3: Wrote 80 bytes for a total of 1293

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex

debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex

debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex

debug1: No valid Key exchange context

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic

debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic

debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic

debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.15.61.

Nasty PTR record "61" is set up for 10.0.15.61, ignoring

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information



debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey

debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa

debug3: send_pubkey_test

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug3: Wrote 624 bytes for a total of 1917

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/identity

debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/identity

debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa

debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa

debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa

debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug3: authmethod_lookup password

debug3: remaining preferred: ,password

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password

debug1: Next authentication method: password

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2061

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

Permission denied, please try again.

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2205

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

Permission denied, please try again.

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2349

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please do include the actual commands you've used in .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @JakubKania Sorry for that, I've added build details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab - failed to authenticate remote server for CI and CD build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434818/gitlab-failed-to-authenticate-remote-server-for-ci-and-cd-build)

Comment: Did you test connection locally? There seems to be so many of these similar issues with no answers, including mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290734/ssh-host-key-verification-failed-inside-gitlab-ci

Comment: IIRC, I'd never tried that when running gitlab-ci since then, just to avoid the failures. Digging into the error message about the key format may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 624 bytes for a total of 1917
```

The private key was rejected.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2061
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2205
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2349
```

It asks for password, which can not be provided from the script. Check the configuration on the server B

Comment: @JakubKania what? This was probably intended as a comment to the question, isn't it?

Comment: Oh my, yes, yes it was.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get you. By creating key pair without passphrase and using ssh-agent, it should not ask for any more password. Is that right? I checked the /etc/ssh/sshd_config on server B, and added `RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys`. But ended with no luck

Comment: The only offered key is rejected by the server. If the key from agent should be offered, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

> key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

This means that the you have a misformatted key, the key from your variable /dev/fd/63 is never offered. Please check the formatting of your variable.